# Getting on and off errors on Codedeploy about appspec

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

I am having a weird issue in CodePipeline + CodeDeploy, we have checked all the aws forums and stackoverflow but no one has had the particular issue and close issues suggestion have been already been taken into account but nothing has helped.

The issue in particular is the following :
We have a CodePipeline:
It happens that "randomly" we get the error:
(x) An AppSpec file is required, but could not be found in the revision

But the required file is in the Revision, we have checked dozens of times, and the files are in there and are the same name and format as the times that follow without problems.
This is happening in the same Deployment Group, with the same configuration, so is not a poorly configured Group because most of the times work without issues.

Just to be sure i add both .yml and .yaml versions in the revision. And the appspec is as simple as this:

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:task-definition/my_app_cd:258"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "nginx_main"
          ContainerPort: 80
        PlatformVersion: null
```

Comment: Is it blue/green deployment or rolling for ecs?

Comment: Blue/green deployment

Answer (score 0):

The above error I suspect is related to the wrong configuration for your codepipeline. To perform ECS codedeploy deployments, the provider in your codepipeline stage for deployment must be "ECS (blue/green)" not "Codedeploy" ( codedeploy is used for EC2 deployments.

Even though in the back-end it uses codedeploy, the name of the provider is "ECS (blue/green)".

#### Pipeline configuration can be checked as:

```
$ aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name <pipeline_name>

{
        "name": "Deploy",
        "blockers": null,
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Deploy",
            "actionTypeId": {
              "category": "Deploy",
              "owner": "AWS",
              "provider": "CodeDeploy",          <===== should be "CodeDeployToECS"
              "version": "1"
            },
```

Comment: You are totally right in the part that provider says CodeDeploy, how can i change this from the console?

currently Deploy stage json is:
```
 {
                "name": "Deploy",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Deploy",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeDeploy",
                            "version": "1"
                        },....
```

Comment: See Step8 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html#tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy-pipeline